# AddEventListener only working with Id and not class

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Trying to create a white box when the first button has been clicked. Oddly enough it only works when I attach an even handler to the I.D. and not to a class. I am either using addEventListener with Class wrong, or calling Class the wrong way. Feel free to correct and thank you!

## This is working with ID

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',domloaded,false);
function domloaded(){
  var bttn = document.getElementById('bttn');


   bttn.addEventListener('click', draw, true);

  function draw(){

   var box = document.getElementById('box');
    box.style.background = 'white';
    box.style.display = 'block';
  }

}
```

```css
/* line 5, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* line 22, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
html {
  line-height: 1;
}

/* line 24, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* line 26, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* line 28, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* line 30, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
/* line 103, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

/* line 32, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
a img {
  border: none;
}

/* line 116, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

/* line 3, ../sass/main.scss */
body {
  background-color: darkred;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* line 9, ../sass/main.scss */
button {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  background: yellow;
}

/* line 16, ../sass/main.scss */
#box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}

/* line 24, ../sass/main.scss */
#drawing_container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="drawing_container">
    <button id="bttn"></button>
    <button id="bttn"></button>
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

## This is working with Class

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',domloaded,false);
function domloaded(){
  var bttn = document.getElementsByClassName('bttn');


   bttn.addEventListener('click', draw, true);

  function draw(){

   var box = document.getElementById('box');
    box.style.background = 'white';
    box.style.display = 'block';
  }

}
```

```css
/* line 5, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* line 22, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
html {
  line-height: 1;
}

/* line 24, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* line 26, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* line 28, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* line 30, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
/* line 103, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

/* line 32, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
a img {
  border: none;
}

/* line 116, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

/* line 3, ../sass/main.scss */
body {
  background-color: darkred;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* line 9, ../sass/main.scss */
button {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  background: yellow;
}

/* line 16, ../sass/main.scss */
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}

/* line 24, ../sass/main.scss */
#drawing_container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="drawing_container">
    <button class="bttn"></button>
    <button class="bttn"></button>
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Once again, my eternal thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This yields the following error:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'bttn.addEventListener('click', draw, true)')
domloaded (js, line 125)
```

This error occurs because you're calling `addEventListener` on `getElementsByClassName`, which returns a NodeList (which is basically an array of elements).

Because it's an array of elements (it *is* getElement**s**ByClassName, after all), you have to either select one element from the array or loop through and add it to all of them.

In this case, the former is fine (there's only one that you want to add it to, for now), but the latter is a safer way of doing it:

```
var bttn = document.getElementsByClassName("bttn");
for(var i = 0; i < bttn.length; i++) {
  bttn[i].addEventListener("click", draw, true);
}
```

Also note that in the CSS, you changed the `box` selector to a class as well, without changing `box` to a class. You don't need to do this:

```
#box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', domloaded, false);

function domloaded() {
  var bttn = document.getElementsByClassName('bttn');
  for (var i = 0; i < bttn.length; i++) {
    bttn[i].addEventListener("click", draw, true);
  }

  function draw() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    box.style.background = 'white';
    box.style.display = 'block';
  }

}
```

```css
/* line 5, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* line 22, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

html {
  line-height: 1;
}
/* line 24, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
/* line 26, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/* line 28, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

caption,
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* line 30, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

q,
blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
/* line 103, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

q:before,
q:after,
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
/* line 32, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

a img {
  border: none;
}
/* line 116, ../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
/* line 3, ../sass/main.scss */

body {
  background-color: darkred;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* line 9, ../sass/main.scss */

button {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  background: yellow;
}
/* line 16, ../sass/main.scss */

#box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}
/* line 24, ../sass/main.scss */

#drawing_container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="drawing_container">
    <button class="bttn"></button>
    <button class="bttn"></button>
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Astro, just one final question. What tool did you use to find the TypeError? Thanks!

Comment: @Razroo-Chief I just looked in the browser console (if you're running the JS in a browser or in some kind of tool, like JSFiddle or Stack Snippets here, you should be able to see errors in the developer tools console specific to your browser).

Answer (score 3):

need to iterate over array of element element while getElementByClassName is called as it returns array of the elements.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',domloaded,false);
function domloaded(){


  var bttn = document.getElementsByClassName('bttn');

  for(var i = 0; i < bttn.length; i++) {
      bttn[i].addEventListener("click", draw, true);
  }


  function draw(){

   var box = document.getElementById('box');
    box.style.background = 'white';
    box.style.display = 'block';
  }

}
```

Comment: Since he has 2 elements with the class name 'bttn' and he need to apply to them both, this won't work.

Comment: It's almost like you just watch your StackOverflow account your whole day! People answer so instantly.

Answer (score 1):

The getElementsByClassName function returns a array containing the elements. Therefore, you will need to iterate over the elements and add a event listener to each item in the array.

ex:

```
for(var i = 0; i < bttn.length; i++){
    bttn[i].addEventListener("click",draw,true)
}
```